# Tooltips of JTableHeader is not showing the width of its column

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jtableheader

I am trying to make the tooltip of my `JTableHeader` showing the width of column it belongs, but it's not working. The tooltip is not showing.

Here's my `JTableHeader`:

```
myTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {{ label1, label2, label3, label4} }, 
new String[] { "foo", "bar", "foo bar", "bar foo" }));

final JTableHeader header = new TableHeaderTooltipWidth(myTable.getColumnModel());
header.setReorderingAllowed(false); 
header.setResizingAllowed(true);
```

`TableHeaderTooltipWidth` is a subclass of `JTableHeader` where I override the method `public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)`, after reading the [Official Tutorial How to use Tool tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html).

```
package gui.paneles.elementos;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class TableHeaderTooltipWidth extends JTableHeader {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public TableHeaderTooltipWidth() {

}
public TableHeaderTooltipWidth(TableColumnModel model) {
    super();
}

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
        int col = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        return String.valueOf(this.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getPreferredWidth());
    }
}
```

But the tooltips is not showing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you registered tootip-component TooltipManager.registerComponent()?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, neither had the tutorial mentioned it. Please answer if you know more about it. The [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html#registerComponent(javax.swing.JComponent)) says: **Registers a component for tooltip management. This will register key bindings to show and hide the tooltip text only if component has focus bindings. This is done so that components that are not normally focus traversable, such as JLabel, are not made focus traversable as a result of invoking this method.** I don't know if it's revelent.

Comment: Here to mention you @agilob

Comment: I tried to register the header to the TooltipsManager, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..., after reading the Official Tutorial How to use Tool tips.

Also check out: [Specifying Tool Tips for Column Headers - How to Use Tables (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#headertooltip)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableHeaderTooltipWidthTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {{ "label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"} }, 
        new String[] { "foo", "bar", "foo bar", "bar foo" });
    // How to Use Tables (The Java™ Tutorials)
    // Specifying Tool Tips for Column Headers
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#headertooltip
    JTable table = new JTable(model) {
      //Implement table header tool tips.
      @Override protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
        return new JTableHeader(columnModel) {
          @Override public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
            int col = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            return String.valueOf(getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getPreferredWidth());
            //int index = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getPoint().x);
            //int realIndex = columnModel.getColumn(index).getModelIndex();
            //return String.valueOf(columnModel.getColumn(realIndex).getPreferredWidth());
          }
        };
      }
    };
    return new JScrollPane(table);
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new TableHeaderTooltipWidthTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I now understand that you mean I have to wrap the `JTableHeader` into a user-defined subclass of `JTable`, implementing its `createDefaultTableHeader()`. along with `getToolTipText()` to make it work. Your code works individually, however after integrating your code in my code, my table is totally gone. In your reference I found more methods to be implemented in `class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel `, which is too much to do and unnecessary in my case. So as a result, I gave up the idea of seeing the column width in tooltip, and use a screen ruler to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use mouse coordination and calculate the position of the mouse according to your table header needs a good  math equation to do that

Comment: I think by `int col = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());` I have achieved this. In [DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#columnAtPoint(java.awt.Point)) it says about `columnAtPoint()` **Returns the index of the column that point lies in, or -1 if the result is not in the range [0, getColumnCount()-1].**. It's getting the coordination, or am I wrong?

Comment: if you try it and it work that means that the good math equation is in that method and some has don it then use it i didn't look for a solution i just gide you nice don you helped me too by this comment thank you

Comment: Ah, by saying "I have archived this" I meant "I think I was getting the coordination but the tooltip is still missing, so the problem is not in not getting the coordination". Sorry for the misleading comment.